# How to export the jQuery dataTable as CSV?

Tags: jquery, csv, datatables

I am trying to export the dataTable Grid as `CSV`. I searched and found out that i have to use [TableTools](https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/). But i don't have this plugin. Previously i was stealing this versions of dataTable:

```
steal("vendor/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.js").then(
    "vendor/datatables-plugins/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js",
    "vendor/datatables-plugins/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css",
    "vendor/datatables-colreorder/js/dataTables.colReorder.js",
    "vendor/datatables-colreorder/css/dataTables.colReorder.css");
```

So i searched and found out in this [link](https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/):

> This extension has now been retired and has been replaced by the
>   Buttons and Select extensions. The documentation is retained for
>   legacy reference only. New projects should use Buttons and Select in
>   preference to TableTools.

So i steal this requirements for having the buttons:

```
steal("vendor/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.js").then(
    "vendor/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.js",
    "vendor/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.js",
    "vendor/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.js",
    "vendor/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.js",
    "vendor/datatables.net-buttons-dt/css/buttons.dataTables.css");
```

and added the buttons in the jquery dataTable.

```
 buttons: [
             'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
          ]
```

The code for the dataTable is below:

```
    this.dataTable = this.$reportGrid.dataTable({
        "aaData": aaData,
        "aaSorting": aaSorting,
        "aLengthMenu": this.options.pageSizes,
        "aoColumns": aoColumns,
        //"asStripeClasses": ["odd-row", "even-row"],
        "autoWidth": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bSort": this.options.allowSort === undefined ? true : this.options.allowSort,
        "stateSave": true,
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "footerCallback": function (nFoot, aData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay) {
            if (that.data.totals) {
                that.$tfoot.html(that.getTemplatePath(that.options.tmplFooter), that.data);
            } else {
                that.$tfoot.empty();
            }
        },
        "fnStateLoadParams": function (oSettings, oData) {
            oData.iStart = 0;
            /* Reset the initial row displayed to be the first one. */
            oData.aaSorting = oSettings.aaSorting;
            /* Use the sorting supplied, not the one saved. */
            oData.oSearch = oSettings.oSearch;
            /* Use the search options supplied, not the ones saved. */
            oData.ColReorder = [];
            /* Empty this saved column reordering */
        },
        "pageLength": this.options.pageSize,
        "displayStart": 0,
        "language": {
            "info": "Displaying rows _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_",
            "lengthMenu": "Show  _MENU_  rows at a time",
            "paginate": {
                "first": "First",
                "last": "Last",
                "previous": "Prev",
                "next": "Next"
            },
            "searchPlaceholder": "Search..."
        },
        "sDom": this.buildsDom(),
        buttons: [
           'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ],
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "sScrollX": this.options.scrollX,
        "drawCallback": function (o) {
            if (that.options.autoHeight) {
                that.adjustGridHeightToContainer();
            }
            that.removeTableInlineOverflowStyle();
            if (that.element != null) {
                can.trigger(that.element, 'grid_drawn');
            }
        }
    });
```

But when i ran the code, the buttons didn't show up. I tried like below also:

```
 "buttons": [
               'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
            ]
```

How can i use this?? Is there any way to export the csv file with less change or anything extra i need to include??

Comment: If anyone gives downvote, then he/she should comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could export `dataTable` as `CSV` working using the existing [TableTools](https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/).
For that i have include the required plugins:

```
 "datatables-tabletools/dataTables.tableTools.js",
 "datatables-tabletools/dataTables.tableTools.css"
```

And then added below code to the code in my question for adding the button for `CSV`:

```
  //Added Export Button for DataTable
        var tableTools = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools(this.dataTable, {
            "sSwfPath": "vendor/datatables-tabletools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": [{
                "sExtends": "csv",
                "sButtonText": "Export"
            }]
        });
        tableTools.fnResizeButtons();
        $('.DT-lf-right', this.element).append($(tableTools.fnContainer()));
```

It's simple and works fine now.

Comment: Is this solution working good also with datatable.js server-side paginated?

Comment: I didn't try it. You can try it and let us know here

Comment: TableTools retired, you should update based on alterations: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/ and https://datatables.net/extensions/select/